# WordPress URL rewrite for custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL

http://classexample.com/student-details/?cname=btech&sname=xyz

I want to convert it like

http://classexample.com/student-details/btech/xyz

and also want the value btech and xyz using php

I have tried

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^student-details/([\w+]*)/([\w+]*)/', 'index.php/?pagename=student-details&cname=$matches[1]&sname=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

but could not succeed

Any Help will be appreciated!

Comment: did you try resetting permalinks after this?

Comment: @ShravanShrama  why I need a resetting permalinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use with this

```
function custom_rewrite_tags() {
      add_rewrite_tag('%cname%', '([^&]+)');
      add_rewrite_tag('%sname%', '([^&]+)');
    }
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tags', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_basic() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^student-details/([\w+]*)/([\w+]*)/', 'index.php/?pagename=student-details&cname=$matches[1]&sname=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Please reset permalinks because htaccess file updated after saving permalinks